# How can I check if a username is available using ajax?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, redux, registration

I'm using Redux and Django to build a registration form.

1. Using ajax, how can I check if a username is available or not without clicking the submit button?
2. How can I recommend a similar username if the requested one is already reserved?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In django registration redux is an 3rd party registration login form with all functionality, I want to do some change in views.py that I can use Ajax for username to check availability of that username in database , how can I include Ajax any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use input field listeners.

1. On text change -> every so seconds execute a script that checks the current text field value with the one from ajax.
2. On text field Deselect (Whenever user clicks outside of text field) -> execute the previously mentioned script.

If it's taken -> suggest clickable usernames below the input field. (When clicked -> update the text in text field).
If it's not -> green mark.